# flatten two json arrays in one with JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I have follwoing JSON object and I want to get flatten obj from this two array. the key `"enrichment"` sometimes can have more than two elements.

```json
[
  {
    "original": {
      "clientname": "test",
      "mobile": "-",
      "phone": "-"
    },
    "enrichment": {
      "customerId": 1,
      "customerextensionId": 1000
    }
  }
]
```

and I want to have in this form:

```json
[
  {
    "clientname": "test",
    "mobile": "-",
    "phone": "-",
    "enrichment": [
      {
        "customerId": 1,
        "customerextensionId": 1000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "o*": "",   // stands for "original", 
                    // value "" returns sub-elements without the key "original"
        "e*": "&[]" // stands for "enrichment",
                    // &  copies the key from the current level
                    // [] produces an arraywise wrapper
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]